# Stop Youtube video on hide a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video, iframe, modal-dialog

I'm trying to stop a YouTube embed video in the bootstrap mode, but nothing happens. Anyone can help me?

Page: https://www.visiteumtegra.com.br/

```
<div class="modal fade bg-modal show" id="ModalVideofontano1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalVideoTitle" style="display: block;" aria-modal="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">x</button>
        <div class="modal-body mt-5 mb-5 border-0">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe id="videofontano1" class="embed-responsive-item yvideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/smIdBgbsHYg?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#ModalVideofontano1').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $('.yvideo').each(function(){
        $(this).stopVideo();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$('#ModalVideofontano1').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.yvideo').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('src', $(this).prop('src'));
    });
});
```

What it does is reassign the video source and therefore defaulting it back to it's original behavior which is stopped.